# Comment section doen not work correctly when using ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new in rails and I'm trying to add review for an item without reloading that page. But when I clicked submit, It showed me duplicate reviews and didn't show the rated point which were made before. If I refresh that page everything is back to normal.

in my routes.rb:

```
resources :items do 
  resources :reviews
end
```

in review_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.item_id = @item.id
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
        if @review.save
          format.js
          format.html { redirect_to item_path(@item)}
        else
            format.html { render :new}
        end
    end
end
```

in views/reviews/create.js.erb

```
$('#new-review').parent().append("<%= j render @item.reviews %>");
```

in views/items/show.html.erb

```
<div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-md-4">
   <div id = 'new-review'>
      <%= render @item.reviews %>
   </div>
 </div> 
</div>
<h2>Add review</h2>
<%= render "reviews/form" %>

//adding star rating 
<script>
$('.average-review-rating').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    path: '/assets/',
    score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-score')
    }
});
</script>

<script>
$('.review-rating').raty({
readOnly: true,
path: '/assets/', 
score: function() {
return $(this).attr('data-score');
}
});
</script>
```

in reviews/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([@item, @item.reviews.build], remote: true) do |f|  %>
  <div id ="rating-form">
    <label>Rating</label>
  </div>
 <%= f.label :comment %> 
 <%= f.text_field :comment, class: "form-control" %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

<script>
$('#rating-form').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    scoreName: 'review[rating]'
});
</script>    

I took the rating star from jquery.raty
And this is what happened:


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkaFP.png
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you should separate layout for your review in separate partial and then load in `*.js.erb` file only it. You rendering `@item.reviews` once again everytime now. JS code for rating should be also in `*.js.erb` file to fire up on ajax complete.